# Random cut forest anomaly detection on multi variant without time series data

Tags: random-forest, amazon-sagemaker, anomaly-detection

I went through various article/blog on aws sagemaker unsupervised ml algo called random cut forest, i saw all the examples are based on time series data, i have a doubt, is random cut forest detects anomaly only on time series data or can it detect anomaly from data sample with multi variant none time series data also?
My use case to detect based on detecting anomaly based on sudden increase in specific event for eg

```
event1,event2,event3,device
100,1,1,device1
1,100,100,device2
1,1,1,device3
```

In this case, anomaly detection algo should predict anomaly for device1 and device2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Random Cut Forest should work well for your use-case. I agree that samples are a bit limited ; in practice you can apply this algo to any multi-variate numerical dataset.